# how insert Silverlight DLL into WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, dll

I was a problem while Silverlight DLL into WPF Application adding:

> The type 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. C:....\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\YeniWPF_SilverlightDLL\YeniWPF_SilverlightDLL\MainWindow.xaml.cs    26  13  YeniWPF_SilverlightDLL

Comment: You can't. ... The Aristocrats.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to include a Silverlight DLL into a WPF application. Although they both use the .NET language they are compiled differently and therefore are not compatible with each other. Silverlight runs under the Silverlight plug-in and has a cut-down version of the .NET library.

If you have access to the original source-code you can re-use the code by **LINKING** the .cs file into the WPF application. That way when the WPF application is built it will compile the .cs file into the correct type.

As Will points out, if you are using .NET 4 or above, you could also build a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you have the original source-code.

Comment: Or move reusable code into a PCL.